VS code test explorer keeps running after test end
I'm using VS code with playwright to build a TAS. I have found VS code's test explorer tool ver useful. However after recently updating VS code, the test explorer has broken.
After all my tests have ran, the explorer keeps running for about another minute, I can't use the stop button or start any other tests until this stops. As you can see in the screenshot, all test pass within 23.8 seconds, but the test explorer kept running until 103.0 seconds

Has anyone else experienced this problem, or know of a way to fix?
Tried running tests with test explorer
Test explorer keeps running after all tests have finished, and no new runs can be started till this ends
this happens with all tests even if the test is empty so shouldnt be to do with how tests are written
package.json below
{
  "name": "playwright_automation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "",
    "test": "npx playwright test --project=chromium",
    "posttest": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.47.0",
    "@testomatio/reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.25",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.7",
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hygen": "^6.2.11",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "playwright": "^1.41.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}


package.json, vscode version and a minimal code that reproduces the problem would be good. Does the same problem happen with one test that just asserts true is true and exits, or is it something specific to your code? Does the same problem happen with other Playwright versions or environments? Try to isolate and minimize so you can determine exactly what the problem is.

Vs code version is 1.93.1, affects all tests, even when asserting true is true and I've updated the question with the pacakge.json
